# I Added custom Select Box in the woocommerce checkout .How to save data that so that in future orders he does not need to select the value again

Tags: php, select, woocommerce, box

I added custom Select Box in the woocommerce checkout . I just want that the value first time entered by logged in customer gets saved in his user meta so that in future orders he does not need to select the value from custom select box again.
Every thing else working fine

below is the code

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'wps_add_select_checkout_field');
function wps_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {


echo '<h3>'.__('Locality').'</h3>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
    'label'         => __( 'Deliverable Locations' ),
    'required'  => true,
    'options'       => array(
        'blank'     => __( 'Select a Locality', 'wps' ),
        'morning'   => __( 'opt1', 'wps' ),
        'afternoon' => __( 'opt2', 'wps' ),
        'evening'   => __( 'opt2', 'wps' )
    )
```

),

```
$checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));

}
//* Process the checkout
  add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wps_select_checkout_field_process');
  function wps_select_checkout_field_process() {
  global $woocommerce; 


// Check if set, if its not set add an error.
if ($_POST['daypart'] == "blank")
 wc_add_notice( '<strong>Please select a locality </strong>', 'error' );

}


//* Update the order meta with field value
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
 function wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

 if ($_POST['daypart']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'daypart', esc_attr($_POST['daypart']));

 }

//* Display field value on the order edition page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address',
```

'wps_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
    function wps_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){

```
echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery option').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'daypart', true ) . '</p>';
```

}

```
//* Add selection field value to emails
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'wps_select_order_meta_keys');
function wps_select_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {

$keys['Daypart:'] = 'daypart';
return $keys;
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you run your code (or does it just not work)?